# Attempted to allocate 3000288 bytes (3000288 * 1) Error: Error: Failed to allocate memory when ASAN enabled

Tags: address-sanitizer

I have a project that I want to enable ASAN for. So far I've been adding these flags to the compiler

`-fsanitize=address -O1 -fno-omit-frame-pointer`.

My project accepts arguments that will try to allocate more or less memory, I have had no issues running it with several arguments, but when I enable ASAN, it always returns this error:

```
Error: Error: failed to allocate memory
Attempted to allocate 3000288 bytes (3000288 * 1)
```

Specifically `3000288 bytes`, no matter the arguments.

I tried running it with `LSAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=1:log_threads=1:log_pointers=1`

I'm completely new to using ASAN so please bear with me, I'll make edits as appropriate.

This is the output:

```
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__isoc99_printf'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__isoc99_sprintf'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__isoc99_snprintf'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__isoc99_fprintf'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__isoc99_vprintf'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__isoc99_vsprintf'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__isoc99_vsnprintf'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__isoc99_vfprintf'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept 'xdr_quad_t'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept 'xdr_u_quad_t'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept 'xdr_destroy'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept 'crypt'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept 'crypt_r'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64b01ab0 of size 112
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__cxa_throw'
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf64501e80 of size 128
==2400194==Registered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf64501e80 of size 128
==2400194==Unregistered root region at 0x7fdf647007a0 of size 32
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: failed to intercept '__cxa_rethrow_primary_exception'
==2400194==AddressSanitizer: libc interceptors initialized
|| `[0x10007fff8000, 0x7fffffffffff]` || HighMem    ||
|| `[0x02008fff7000, 0x10007fff7fff]` || HighShadow ||
|| `[0x00008fff7000, 0x02008fff6fff]` || ShadowGap  ||
|| `[0x00007fff8000, 0x00008fff6fff]` || LowShadow  ||
|| `[0x000000000000, 0x00007fff7fff]` || LowMem     ||
MemToShadow(shadow): 0x00008fff7000 0x000091ff6dff 0x004091ff6e00 0x02008fff6fff
redzone=16
max_redzone=2048
quarantine_size_mb=256M
thread_local_quarantine_size_kb=1024K
malloc_context_size=30
SHADOW_SCALE: 3
SHADOW_GRANULARITY: 8
SHADOW_OFFSET: 0x7fff8000
==2400194==Installed the sigaction for signal 11
==2400194==Installed the sigaction for signal 7
==2400194==Installed the sigaction for signal 8
==2400194==T0: FakeStack created: 0x7fdf629f7000 -- 0x7fdf63500000 stack_size_log: 20; mmapped 11300K, noreserve=0 
==2400194==T0: stack [0x7ffc9b172000,0x7ffc9b972000) size 0x800000; local=0x7ffc9b96ff70
==2400194==AddressSanitizer Init done
Error: Error: failed to allocate memory
==2400195==Ignored: chunk 0x60b000000040-0x60b0000000aa of size 106.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x000000797760-0x0000007a4c60.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x0000007a4f38-0x00000181ffa0.
==2400195==0x00000181fa80: found 0x612000000040 pointing into chunk 0x612000000040-0x612000000158 of size 280.
==2400195==0x00000181faa0: found 0x60b0000001a0 pointing into chunk 0x60b0000001a0-0x60b000000208 of size 104.
==2400195==0x00000181fac0: found 0x60b0000000f0 pointing into chunk 0x60b0000000f0-0x60b000000158 of size 104.
==2400195==0x00000181fae0: found 0x60b000000250 pointing into chunk 0x60b000000250-0x60b0000002b8 of size 104.
==2400195==0x00000181fb00: found 0x60b000000300 pointing into chunk 0x60b000000300-0x60b000000368 of size 104.
==2400195==0x00000181fb20: found 0x60b0000003b0 pointing into chunk 0x60b0000003b0-0x60b000000418 of size 104.
==2400195==0x00000181fb40: found 0x60b000000460 pointing into chunk 0x60b000000460-0x60b0000004c8 of size 104.
==2400195==0x00000181fb60: found 0x60c000000e80 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000e80-0x60c000000ef8 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fb80: found 0x60c000000f40 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000f40-0x60c000000fb8 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fba0: found 0x60c000001000 pointing into chunk 0x60c000001000-0x60c000001078 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fbc0: found 0x60c0000001c0 pointing into chunk 0x60c0000001c0-0x60c000000238 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fbe0: found 0x60c000000280 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000280-0x60c0000002f8 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fc00: found 0x60c000000340 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000340-0x60c0000003b8 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fc20: found 0x60c000000400 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000400-0x60c000000478 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fc40: found 0x60c000000580 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000580-0x60c0000005f8 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fc60: found 0x60c000000640 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000640-0x60c0000006b8 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fc80: found 0x60c000000700 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000700-0x60c000000778 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fca0: found 0x60c000000d00 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000d00-0x60c000000d78 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fcc0: found 0x60c0000013c0 pointing into chunk 0x60c0000013c0-0x60c000001438 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fce0: found 0x60c0000004c0 pointing into chunk 0x60c0000004c0-0x60c000000538 of size 120.
==2400195==0x00000181fd00: found 0x60c0000007c0 pointing into chunk 0x60c0000007c0-0x60c000000834 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fd20: found 0x60c000000880 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000880-0x60c0000008f4 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fd40: found 0x60c000000940 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000940-0x60c0000009b4 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fd60: found 0x60c000000a00 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000a00-0x60c000000a74 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fd80: found 0x60c000000ac0 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000ac0-0x60c000000b34 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fda0: found 0x60c000000b80 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000b80-0x60c000000bf4 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fdc0: found 0x60c000000c40 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000c40-0x60c000000cb4 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fde0: found 0x60c0000010c0 pointing into chunk 0x60c0000010c0-0x60c000001134 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fe00: found 0x60c000001180 pointing into chunk 0x60c000001180-0x60c0000011f4 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fe20: found 0x60c000001240 pointing into chunk 0x60c000001240-0x60c0000012b4 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fe40: found 0x60c000001300 pointing into chunk 0x60c000001300-0x60c000001374 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fe60: found 0x60c000000dc0 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000dc0-0x60c000000e34 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fe80: found 0x60c000000100 pointing into chunk 0x60c000000100-0x60c000000174 of size 116.
==2400195==0x00000181fea0: found 0x60e000000040 pointing into chunk 0x60e000000040-0x60e0000000d8 of size 152.
==2400195==0x00000181fec0: found 0x616000000080 pointing into chunk 0x616000000080-0x616000000290 of size 528.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x7fdf66500d60-0x7fdf66501140.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x7fdf6616f030-0x7fdf6617f488.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x7fdf65e80ba8-0x7fdf65e854c0.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x7fdf65c64d80-0x7fdf65c65bc0.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x7fdf65a5cd68-0x7fdf65a5d0a0.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x7fdf658565d0-0x7fdf65859aa0.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x7fdf65640c30-0x7fdf656412d0.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x7fdf65420750-0x7fdf654298e0.
==2400195==0x7fdf654256e8: found 0x621000000100 pointing into chunk 0x621000000100-0x621000001100 of size 4096.
==2400195==Scanning GLOBAL range 0x7fdf66730380-0x7fdf66732210.
==2400195==Processing thread 2400194.
==2400195==Scanning REGISTERS range 0x7fdf665e1000-0x7fdf665e1b60.
==2400195==Stack at 0x7ffc9b172000-0x7ffc9b972000 (SP = 0x7ffc9b96fae8).
==2400195==Scanning STACK range 0x7ffc9b96fae8-0x7ffc9b972000.
==2400195==0x7ffc9b96fd70: found 0x619000000582 pointing into chunk 0x619000000580-0x619000000980 of size 1024.
==2400195==0x7ffc9b96fe20: found 0x602000000010 pointing into chunk 0x602000000010-0x602000000020 of size 16.
==2400195==0x7ffc9b96ff00: found 0x603000000010 pointing into chunk 0x603000000010-0x603000000028 of size 24.
==2400195==Scanning FAKE STACK range 0x7fdf62b00000-0x7fdf62b00080.
==2400195==Scanning FAKE STACK range 0x7fdf62c00000-0x7fdf62c00100.
==2400195==TLS at 0x7fdf6672a440-0x7fdf6672bfc0.
==2400195==Scanning TLS range 0x7fdf6672a440-0x7fdf6672bfc0.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x603000000010-0x603000000028.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x602000000010-0x602000000020.
==2400195==0x602000000010: found 0x619000000080 pointing into chunk 0x619000000080-0x619000000480 of size 1024.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x619000000080-0x619000000480.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x619000000580-0x619000000980.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x621000000100-0x621000001100.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x616000000080-0x616000000290.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60e000000040-0x60e0000000d8.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000100-0x60c000000174.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000dc0-0x60c000000e34.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000001300-0x60c000001374.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000001240-0x60c0000012b4.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000001180-0x60c0000011f4.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c0000010c0-0x60c000001134.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000c40-0x60c000000cb4.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000b80-0x60c000000bf4.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000ac0-0x60c000000b34.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000a00-0x60c000000a74.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000940-0x60c0000009b4.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000880-0x60c0000008f4.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c0000007c0-0x60c000000834.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c0000004c0-0x60c000000538.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c0000013c0-0x60c000001438.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000d00-0x60c000000d78.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000700-0x60c000000778.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000640-0x60c0000006b8.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000580-0x60c0000005f8.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000400-0x60c000000478.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000340-0x60c0000003b8.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000280-0x60c0000002f8.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c0000001c0-0x60c000000238.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000001000-0x60c000001078.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000f40-0x60c000000fb8.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60c000000e80-0x60c000000ef8.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60b000000460-0x60b0000004c8.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60b0000003b0-0x60b000000418.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60b000000300-0x60b000000368.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60b000000250-0x60b0000002b8.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60b0000000f0-0x60b000000158.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60b0000001a0-0x60b000000208.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x612000000040-0x612000000158.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60b000000040-0x60b0000000aa.
==2400195==Processing platform-specific allocations.
==2400195==Scanning leaked chunks.
==2400195==Scanning HEAP range 0x60b000000040-0x60b0000000aa.
Attempted to allocate 3000288 bytes (3000288 * 1)
```